# Neo4J Remote client accepts

Tags: neo4j

Are the only two valid options for securing the remote client accepts via the org.neo4j.server.webserver.address property in the conf/neo4j-server.properties file to only accept connections from the local host (where the line is commented out), or uncommenting it and specifying `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0` which enables access to any host?

Is it not possible to specify a specific ip Address, if for example your application is running on a separate server to where you have installed your Neo4j server?  Presumably if this is not possible you'd have to use firewall rules to restrict access would you?

Comment: did you find solution?I also want same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an IP address to listen on. And you can use [https and auth-rules](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/security-server.html) to secure your Neo4j server.

And there is the [authentication-extension](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension) for adding basic-auth.

Comment: Authentication-extension : what if i want to access neo4j from browser.

Comment: https and auth-rules : how to do this,should i write PermanentlyFailingSecurityRule class and where should i put this class?